# Firefox @font-face Text Flickers After Every AJAX Response

Tags: .net, ajax, firefox, font-face, webfonts

I have a .NET page with a custom @font-face that is displaying and working correctly in all browsers. This page makes partial postbacks to load additional content in the background, hidden from the user. Everything is playing nicely together, except when I do a hard refresh (Ctrl+F5) in Firefox, which decides to reapply the @font-face after each AJAX response.

When I say it reapplies the @font-face, I mean it makes a request for the font (which Firebug shows with a status of "200 (BFCache)", so it's not going back to the server), and all the text using the @font-face flashes. I am making many AJAX requests each time the page loads, so it can be quite annoying to see all the page text flash on each response.

Does anyone have any ideas to make Firefox play nicely?